# .then() / .done() doesn't work as expected - jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise

Here is an example:

```
function firstFun() {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();

  return dfd.reject();
}

function secondFun() {
  console.log('in secondFun');
}

console.log('start');

firstFun().then(secondFun());
```

Nevertheless I return `dfd.reject()` the `secondFun()` is fired.

the same with  `firstFun().done(secondFun());`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `firstFun().then(secondFun);`

`.then` and `.done` expect function as parameters to be used as callbacks. But you're invoking `secondFun` instead of just passing it (hence actually passing `undefined`).

Comment: Thank you very much for it. It does work perfectly. (Gonna accept it after 10 min) Again, thank you very much.